# DFS and BFS with adjacency matrix counted in Java

Tags: java, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search, adjacency-matrix

Currently trying to build a program that can implement both DFS and BFS in Java by taking in an adjacency matrix from a file and printing out the following info: order that vertices are first encountered, order that vertices become dead ends, number of components, and the tree edges.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProjectDriver {

    public static int count;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        ArrayList<Integer> dfsDeadEnd = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> dfsVertices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> bfsVertices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int dfsComponents = 0;
        int bfsComponents = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("sample1.txt"));

        int n = 8;
        int[][] edges = new int[n][n];
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];
        count = 0;

        for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < n; j++) {
                 edges[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            visited[i] = false;
        }

        int[][] BFStreeEdgeGraph = new int[n][n];
        int[][] DFStreeEdgeGraph = new int[n][n];
        int[][] crossGraph = new int[n][n];

        for(int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j <= n-1; j++){
                    DFStreeEdgeGraph[i][j] = 0;
                    BFStreeEdgeGraph[i][j] = 0;
                    crossGraph[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++){
            if(visited[i] == false){
                dfs(edges,i,visited, dfsVertices, dfsDeadEnd, DFStreeEdgeGraph);
                dfsDeadEnd.add(i);
                dfsComponents++;
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i <= n-1; i++) {
                if(visited[i] == false) {
                    bfs(edges, i, visited, bfsVertices, BFStreeEdgeGraph);
                    bfsComponents++;
                }
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("DFS: Number of Connected Components: " + dfsComponents);
        System.out.print("DFS: Order of First Encountered: ");
        for(int i : dfsVertices){
            System.out.print((i+1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("DFS: Order of First Dead-Ends: ");
        for(int i : dfsDeadEnd){
            System.out.print((i+1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Tree edges:");
        displayGraph(DFStreeEdgeGraph, n);

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("BFS: Number of Connected Components: " + bfsComponents);
        System.out.print("BFS: Order of First encountered: ");
        for(int i : bfsVertices){
            System.out.print((i+1) + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static void dfs(int[][] edges, int vertex, boolean[] visited, ArrayList<Integer> dfsVertices, ArrayList<Integer> dfsDeadEnd, int[][] DFStreeEdgeGraph) {
            visited[vertex] = true;
            dfsVertices.add(count, vertex);
            count = count + 1;

            for(int w = 0; w <= edges.length-1; w++) {
                if(edges[vertex][w] == 1 && !visited[w]) {
                    DFStreeEdgeGraph[vertex][w] = 1;
                    dfs(edges, w, visited, dfsVertices, dfsDeadEnd, DFStreeEdgeGraph);
                    dfsDeadEnd.add(w);
                }
            }
    }

    public static void bfs(int[][] edges, int vertex, boolean[] visited, ArrayList<Integer> bfsVertices, int[][] BFStreeEdgeGraph) {
            bfsVertices.add(count, vertex);
            count = count + 1;

            for(int w = 0; w < edges.length; w++) {
                if(edges[vertex][w] != 0 && !visited[w]) {
                    visited[vertex] = true;
                }
            }
            for(int w = bfsVertices.indexOf(vertex) + 1; w < bfsVertices.size(); w++) {
                int value = bfsVertices.get(w);
                bfs(edges, value, visited, bfsVertices, BFStreeEdgeGraph);
            }
    }

    public static void displayGraph(int[][] graph, int n) {

            for(int i = 0; i <= n-1; ++i){
                System.out.print("    ");
                for(int j = 0; j <= n-1; ++j){
                    System.out.print(graph[i][j] + " ");
            }
                    System.out.println();
        }
    }   
}
```

And here is the output from running my code:

```
Input graph:
    0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 
    1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
    0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 
    0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 
    1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
    1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 
    0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 
    0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0   

DFS: Number of Connected Components: 1
DFS: Order of First Encountered: 1 2 6 5 7 3 4 8 
DFS: Order of First Dead-Ends: 5 6 8 4 3 7 2 1 

Tree edges:
    0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 
    0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
    0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 


BFS: Number of Connected Components: 0
BFS: Order of First encountered:
```

And here are my issues. For the DFS, my order of first encountered should be `1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8`, but this is not what I'm getting. Additionally, my order of dead ends should be `8 7 5 4 1 2 6 3`, but this is also off. My tree edges managed to come out correct.

For the BFS, I can't get anything to print, and debugging my DFS and BFS methods hasn't given me the answer yet. I'd be very grateful from some help.

Comment: Sorry, this is not how StackOverflow works. Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively. _"Please help me debug my code"_ is off-topic unless you provide (1) the _expected_ output, (2) the _actual_ output, (3) The detailed results of your investigation and debugging.  So far you've provided only (1), and _"debugging my DFS and BFS methods hasn't given me the answer yet"_ is too vague to be useful.  You must have learned _something_ from stepping through the code.

Comment: My post details both my "actual" output of what I got when I ran my program, as well as the expected output. What exactly are you missing?

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you drew a picture of what you think the input graph looks like and added that to the question, so we can tell if your mental model has a flaw.  Also, maybe I'm just missing it but I don't see where you identify the starting node for the search.

Comment: Sorry, I mis-read part of the post. So you provided input and output, but not the resuts of debugging; the picture would be extremely helpful in cross-checking that what you expect is correct.

Comment: My input graph that is read from a file is also included in my original post, in the output. Are you not seeing it? It should be the very first bit matrix in the output.

Comment: I see the matrix defining the graph.  I mean a hand-drawn picture of what you think the graph looks like.  Surely you already have one that you used while debugging, no?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. My DFS graphs (input and tree edges) have printed correctly; it's the two orders that are incorrect. Do you mean what I'm picturing for the BFS graphs? I can include them in my post.

Comment: I drew a picture of your graph on paper.  It is fully connected and fully bi-directional (i.e. the adjacency matrix reflects across the diagonal).  In order for any of your question to have meaning you must have been given instructions on how to choose the starting node.  Also, since it's fully connected and bi-directional there are no leaf (dead-end) nodes.

Comment: The input graph is represented by `int[][] edges` ? Please add the input as a matrix so we can run the code. `int[][] edges = new int[][] {
  {0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0 },
  .....
 };`