# Java DFS for adjacency matrix

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I am working on a project to implement a DFS for a given adjacency matrix. I have the file reading in correctly and I have the program outputting a list of first encountered vertices, however, I am not getting the correct list. I am getting 1 2 6 5 7 3 4 8 but I need to get 1 2 6 7 4 3 5 8. I am not sure where I am going wrong, but any suggestions would help. Below I have attached the part of code the outputs the encountered vertices and the file with the adjacency matrix.

Code with the output:

```
public static void dfs(int vertex, boolean[] visitArray, ArrayList<Integer> DFSvertexList, ArrayList<Integer> DFSdeadEndList, int[][] DFStreeEdgeGraph, ArrayList<Integer> vertexList, ArrayList<Integer> iList, boolean[] visitArray2){
    int ver = 0;
    DFSvertexList.add(vertex);
    visitArray[vertex] = true;

    for(int i = 0; i <= dim-1; i++){
        if(graph[vertex][i] == 1){
            if(!visitArray[i]){
                ver = i;
                DFStreeEdgeGraph[vertex][i] = 1;
                dfs(i, visitArray, DFSvertexList, DFSdeadEndList, DFStreeEdgeGraph, vertexList, iList, visitArray2);
                DFSdeadEndList.add(i);
            }
            else if(i >= vertex && i != ver){
                vertexList.add(vertex+1);
                iList.add(i+1);
            }

        }
    }               
}
```

Here is the adjacency matrix:

```
0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
```

Please let me know if more code is needed.

Comment: Maybe re-do the whole thing and just strictly follow the simple pseudocode from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) page? Do you really need that many parameters?

Comment: I think this person is in the same class as https://stackoverflow.com/q/49377108/18157

Comment: Did your assignment specify how to choose the starting node?  You get different results depending on where you start.  Have you drawn a picture of the graph on paper?  That would probably be extremely helpful.

Comment: @JimGarrison the assignment says " Assume that the vertices are visited in numerical order when no other order is specified by the search." And yes I have the graph drawn out